# Command Link Without page redirect

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

I want to click on an image (commandLink) which redirects to a controllers that calculates the number of clicks and updates a field in the object on return i do not wish to redirect the page however a pop up window should appear to let the user download a file from Documents.

Here's my code. Can someone tell me how to get the outputlink working.. my counter is working fine though.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Docs}" var="d" rendered="{!if(Docs.size>0,true,false)}">

<apex:column >                
 <apex:commandLink action="{!incrementCounter}">
 <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.LibraryImages)}" title="Click to Download" />  
 <apex:param assignTo="{!SelectedId}" name="selId" value="{!d.Id}"/>   
<apex:outputLink value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!d.Document_Id__c}"/>            
 </apex:commandLink>
</apex:column>

<apex:column headerValue="Downloaded" >
   <apex:outputText value="{!d.Counter__c}" />   
  </apex:column>

</apex:pageBlockTable>

-------------------------------------------

 public pagereference incrementCounter()
    {

 UpdateCount = [select id, counter__c from Document_Details__c where id =:SelectedId];  

  Decimal num= updatecount.counter__c;
  updatecount.counter__c=num+1;
  update updatecount;

 Docs.clear();
     // to get the updated values from the object 

Docs=[Select id, Name__c, Document_Id__c,        counter__c,Uploaded_by__c,Type__c,Description__c,Document_Created_On__c,My_Library__c From

Document_Details__c where My_Library__c=: MyLib.id];


 return null;

}
```

I tried to partially refresh the page using outputlink, action support and rerender but that didn't work so i thought of using commandlink.

Answer (score 0):

Elements such as `<apex:actionStatus>` and [`<apex:commandLink>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandLink.htm) have javascript events you can leverage to perform this kind of thing, so I would do something like the following in your page:

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!incrementCounter}"
  oncomplete="window.open('/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!d.Document_Id__c}');">
    <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.LibraryImages)}" title="Click to Download" />  
    <apex:param assignTo="{!SelectedId}" name="selId" value="{!d.Id}"/>   
</apex:commandLink>
```

That way, you call your method to increment the counter, and once that's done the document is opened in a new window as you require.